# Is there any way to configure automatic routing in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel 4, came from codeigniter, I've been trying to code in Laravel and came back and forth to their documentation, my question is, is there a way that the routes could automatically detect the methods of a controller?

i've been using

```
Route::resource('admin','AdminController');
```

but it seems like it only provide same results as

```
Route::get('admin','AdminController@index');
```

Same problem occurs even in the packages, i've been trying to develop a modularized app like what i can achieve in codeigniter where there are modules folder to place different views and controllers.

i just don't want the way that every time i have a new method i also need this to be registered in the routes, it's kinda like a lot of work if you are going to update or enhance your controllers methods.

Comment: You should consider reading this blog by Phil Sturgeon regarding the use of explicit routes, and the many advantages it provides: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for this-
Laravel allows you to easily define a single route to handle every action in a controller using simple, REST naming conventions. First, define the route using the Route::controller method:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

The controller method accepts two arguments. The first is the base URI the controller handles, while the second is the class name of the controller. Next, just add methods to your controller, prefixed with the HTTP verb they respond to:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

public function getIndex()
{
    //
}

public function postProfile()
{
    //
}

}
```

The index methods will respond to the root URI handled by the controller, example-

```
http://localhost/users/
```

for more information refer the [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers)

Comment: the method is now deprecated :(

Comment: https://github.com/themsaid/laravel-routes-publisher can map the implicit to explicit routes .